# Login page and MySqlDataReader exception error

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to create a login page, which looks at the users input, and compares them to the values in the database. More specifically, the username and password.
This is how my code looks:

```
public static void Login(string user, string pass)
    {           
        var con = GetConnection();

        try
        {               
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, password FROM user_data;";
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {                  
                 while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string un = reader.GetString(0);
                    string pw = reader.GetString(1);

                    if (user == un && pass == pw)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
                        con.Close();
                        reader.Close();                               
                    }
                    else if (user != un && pass == pw)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username is incorrect");
                        reader.Close();                            

                    }
                    else if (user == un && pass != pw)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect");
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e));
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

And here is where the method is called:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
    }
```

What it does it takes the users input, and compares the information with the data in my database. The problem is that with the way it is programmed, it starts out by looking at the first row of the table (where it gets the username and password) and checks if the information matches the user input.
If it does, the user is greeted with a pop up window telling them welcome. If the username or password is wrong, the system will tell the user.

I don't have a "else if" statement that tells the program what to do, if neither the username or password is correct, and here is why. It would look like this:

```
else if (user != un && pass != pw)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User does not exist");
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Let's say I make a login with the username and password, on the 6th row of my database. The code will start by checking the first row, and determine that neither of the username and password matches that in the database. Therefore, the message will show "User does not exist". Then it continues with checking the next row, and since the username and password doesn't match there either, the same message will appear. This continues until a match is found.

So I was wondering, how I should change the code so it can, first of all, check if the username exists. If it does, it should check if the password in that row matches the password from the user input. If they both match, log in.

I hope in turn, this also fixes the MySqlDataReader exception error, which says that: "Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed". I think I know why it does it: It's because It jumps out the "if" statement where I ask it to close, and into the "while" statement where it reads my reader.

Comment: Why not just make the SQL query like this `SELECT username, password FROM user_data WHERE username like @username AND password = @password`?

Comment: Using a `WHERE` would make it much easier.  That `SELECT` is otherwise returning all `username` from that table.

Comment: Webbanditten's idea is much better, but as we already have the credentials we could just use `SELECT Count(*) FROM user_data WHERE username like @username AND password = @password', then we can just use an `ExecuteScalar()`. It is not a good security practice to say User exists as it reveals a valid username and a nefarious person could just concentrate on password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do You select all table? You should query for that logins name only with where clause. You can check if there is such user when You see your reader is empty. If it is empty You know there is no such user in database. If reader is not empty You know there is such user in database and u can just simple compare password You got from Reader with Your password.

```
   public static void Login(string user, string pass) {
        var con = GetConnection();

        try {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, password WHERE username = @username";
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    string pw = reader.GetString(1);

                    if (pass == pw) {
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");

                    } else {
                        MessageBox.Show("Password Incorrect");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no such user in database");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e));
        } finally {
            con.Close();
reader.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please replace the `LIKE` in the Sql with an **=**

Comment: Okay, I have tired to set the code up as you have, and used the MySql query that Rafael suggested. This works fine, but I still get the "invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed" when the password is incorrect. Other than that, It's a good point. I don't need to get the entire column, just only the row where the username match. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Maybe put the line that closes reader later in code. It probably tries to read the reader that is closed. I will edit my answer better to show where to change.

Comment: Hmm, if I place it in the "finally" block it tells me it does not exist in the current context. I tired placing it after the "else" block, after the "while" statement and even after the "if" statement. Same error.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. I placed the "reader.Close()" just after my if statement. Before It was after the "if" statement but before the "else" statement. It works now. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem you just need to add a where clause in your select. Something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, password FROM user_data where username = '" + user + "';";
```

With this select you will get just a one record from your table (the username must be unique).
Then you need to put a else condition in HasRows, and just verify the password, if the reader has rows:

```
if (reader.HasRows) {
 ...
} else {
     MessageBox.Show("Username is incorrect");
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. It helped a lot, combined with Whencesoever's answer. :)